# Message Queue timeout invalid value on Linux

Tags: linux, timeout, posix, message-queue

I am trying to send and receive message with linux message queue api

to receive I am using the function after open msgq and get msgq file descriptor:
mq_timedreceive (mqd_t mqdes, char *msg_ptr,
size_t msg_len, unsigned *msg_prio,
const struct timespec *abs_timeout)

I want to set timeout with resolution of milliseconds
following the documentation the function get absolute time
struct timespec tm;
I am using the *clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tm)* to get current time
I want timeout of 100 msec so I add to the nano_seconds result of tm:
tm.tv_nsec+= 100;
with the following parameters:
mq_timedreceive (mqdes,buffer,buffer_len,NULL,&tm);
I get error (errno) EINVAL - invalid paramer

BUT when I change only the second param of tm:
tm.tv_sec+=1;
The function running without any error

Can anyone tell me why I get an error when set the nano seconds param?

Comment: The [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_receive.3.html) says *... because tv_nsec was less than zero or greater than 1000 million.* Is that the case when you get the error?

Comment: (100 msecs requires adding more than 100 to the **nano**seconds.)

Comment: The problem solved Shawn was right in the first comment - the nano param was bigger than it bigger than max value